# 'System.Web.HttpApplication.User' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, roleprovider, user-roles

I am new to MVC3 and I am trying to implement customer user and role Authentication. I am able to validate the user using my custom database but now I want to use my custom roles out of the same table. I followed the instructions from this link below to get this far:

[MVC Custom Roles and Validation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF?fid=1830658&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&select=5061695&fr=1#xx0xx)

The tutorial had me put this block of code in my global.asax file.

```
protected void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
{
    if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported == true)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
        {
            try
            {
                //let us take out the username now
                string roles = string.Empty;
                string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;

                using (RecipeEntities entities = new RecipeEntities())
                {
                   **-->> User user = entities.KeyFobUsers.Single(u => u.username == username);

                    roles = user.AccessLevel.Trim();
                }
                //let us extract the roles from our own custom cookie
                //Let us set the Pricipal with our user specific details
                e.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(username, "Forms"), roles.Split(';'));
            }
            catch
            {
                //something went wrong
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently in the script above MVC has 'User' underlined stating that `'System.Web.HttpApplication.User' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'`

I have googled around and tried the links I found on Stack but nothing was geared towards my issue. I am just trying to get the role out of my custom database table into the Roles of MVC so I can use permissions on certain windows.

Does anyone have any suggestions or want to push me in the right direction?

Comment: The current class must have a property called `User` so you are getting a name collision.  Try specifying the full namespace of the type (assuming you have a class called `User`):  `MyApp.MyNamespace.User user = ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is conflicted with the `User` property of the HttpApplication and the `User` class.  You can use `var` instead to avoid the conflict:

```
var user = entities.KeyFobUsers.Single(u => u.username == username);
```

Or fully qualify the `User` class with the namespace it's in:

```
MyNamespace.User user = ...
```

Comment: I thought the code was setting the User role, I changed it to var and nothing happens. The Role never gets set and I can't get to the page. Its in a try catch but its not throwing any errors. I wish I knew c# better

Comment: I would post that as a new question and include the code that compiles.

Comment: would you not use this way to set user roles?

Comment: I think that's a different question.  Your _first_ question is on the compiler error.  The _next_ question is "why doesn't this set the "User" properly.

Comment: Thanks and done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377909/why-doesnt-this-set-the-user-roles-properly

Comment: I figured out that once I replaced 'User' with my 'DB_TableName' it worked. I don't understand why, but it does. thanks for the help